# Excel : filter with Multiple Criteria : AutoFilter or AdvancedFilter

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter, advanced-filter

I am trying to create a filter that will do the below

Begins with "4" or
Contains "2TWH" or
Contains "2TER"

I believe it will turn out to look like this

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$H$10").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=4*", _
    Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*2TWH*"
```

but I need to somehow also have a criteria 3 for ="=*2TER*"

I did some googling and saw that you can store the values into an array and then  call the array values but I was unable to get them into the array in a usable fashion.

Is anyone able to offer some assistance with this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$H$10").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=4*", _
    Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=Array("*2TWH*","*2TER*")
```

This doesn't throw any error, but ...
it'll **only take 2 criteria because there are wildcards (`*`).**
Here it's the last criteria from the array (here `*2TER*`)

---

Ideally, this would have been nice, as it works for *constants*,
but because you **use WildCards (`*`) it only supports 2 criteria... :/**

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$10").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("*2TWH*", "*2TER*", "4*"), _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

---

---

**So you'll have to go with `AdvancedFilter` :**

```
With ActiveSheet
    'Const xlFilterInPlace = 1
    .Range("$A$5:$H$10").AdvancedFilter _
                        Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
                        CriteriaRange:=WsFilterSettings.Range("A1:A4")
End With 'ActiveSheet
```

`AdvancedFilter` take a **Range as criteria inputs**, `CriteriaRange`, so you'll have to **put on a sheet** :

- the **header of the column** you want to apply to the filter on
- your **criteria** below the respective header (if you have multiples columns)

Each **COLUMN** of that Range, are *linked* by an **AND**
Each **ROW** of that Range, are *linked* by an **OR**
So build your table carefully!

In the above example code, I have used : 
(let's say that your **column's header** was *Column To Filter On*) :

```
A1 | Column To Filter On
A2 | 4*
A3 | *2TWH*
A4 | *2TER*
```

Comment: I like the idea but I need the array value to be ="=*2TWH*" and not just "*2TWH*" etc.

Comment: @MathewHood : See the edit! Nope, you don't, test the second code with only 2 parameters in the array and you'll see that you don't need the `=`! ;) Anyway, **Enjoy advanced filters! ;)**

Comment: @Simulator : The place of "N" in the alphabet ;)

Comment: @R3uK my bad :). Although for some reason the advanced filter is returning all rows and not the columns matching the wildcards.

Comment: @Simulator : Reading back myself, it seems it should be the column's header and not the column's number. Are you trying to filter columns based on their names ?

Comment: I was actually trying to use advanced filter without using a column header, but used it ultimately and worked fine.