# How to use autofilter for more than 2 criteria in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried these two methods, but its not working. Please suggest if there is any easy code for auto-filtering more than 2 Values

(1)

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A4:U2000").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Array("=*" & logic1 & "*", "=*" & logic2 & "*", "=*" & logic3 & "*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

(2)

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A4:U2000").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="=*" & logic1 & "*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*" & logic2 & "*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria3:="=*" & logic3 & "*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria4:="=*" & logic4 & "*"
```

Comment: If you are using wildcards or negation, you will need to create an array of allowed values and use that, or use a formula, or use an advanced filter instead. This has been answered here before.

Comment: As said by Rory, you can't use more than 2 wildcards with `AutoFilter`, personnally I'd go with [`AdvancedFilter` (click here)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42805928/4628637)